# VueJS plugins conflict

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli-4

I created two plugins in my VueJS app powered by Vue CLI 4 but when I tried to use it in my page only one will be working

```
| plugins
|-- axios.vue
|-- authentication.vue
```

**axios.vue**

```js
import Vue from "vue";

Plugin.install = function(Vue) {
  Vue.prototype.$myName = "Dean Armada";
};

Vue.use(Plugin);

export default Plugin;
```

**authentication.vue**

```js
import Vue from "vue";

Plugin.install = function(Vue) {
  Vue.prototype.$name = "Chris Guinto";
};

Vue.use(Plugin);

export default Plugin;
```

**main.js**

```js
import axios from "./plugins/axios.js";
import authentication from "./plugins/authentication.js";

Vue.use(axios);
Vue.use(authentication);
```

**instructions.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
      Hello World
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    created() {
      console.log(this.$name);
      console.log(this.$myName);
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

## TAKE NOTE

- The output above will be "Dean Armada" only and the `console.log(this.$name)` is undefined
- But if I commented out the `Vue.use(axios)` the `console.log(this.$name)` will work so the output will be "Chris Guinto" and the other one is undefined because the `axios` plugin is not activated

So how can I make them both work at the same time?

Comment: This seems very confusing. You're doubling up on your `Vue.use()` calls. Also, `Plugin` is never defined in any of your code and why are you defining plugins in single-file `.vue` components?

Comment: Because that is what document says on creating a Vue plugin. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html

Comment: Right, yeah. Those aren't the most comprehensive instructions. If you're motivated, you could always raise a documentation issue.

Comment: I sure will.. This will help many people

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps try and simplify it a little with the following approach?

```js
// plugins/axios.js
export default {
    install(Vue){   
        Vue.prototype.$myname = "Dean Armada";
    }
}

// plugins/authentication.js
export default {
    install(Vue){   
        Vue.prototype.$name = "Chris Guinto";
    }
}

// main.js
import axios from "./plugins/axios.js";
import authentication from "./plugins/authentication.js";

Vue.use(axios);
Vue.use(authentication);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Comment: Wow it worked! This is great! I just copied the documentation here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html. I did not know it can be done with your simplified approach